# A dupe target with an incomplete answer: is this dupe designation mistaken?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

One of our users has asked a question about the PHB+1 rule in Adventurers League(AL), but [is specifically asking about some ambiguity regarding season 9 sources](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165890/22566).

The title looks like it fits [another AL PHB +1 question begun previously](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110848/22566) but that Q&A has not been updated as the new seasons emerge.  (I just bountied it after a chat with NautArch)

The user is asking about "why is this a dupe when **the answer to my question isn't there**" - which is true.

I think that with best of intentions this may have been an incorrect dupe closure since the answer is not up to date based on the content of the question.

I'd like a ruling on this.

Comment: Well let's see if I gooned up this for you by updating the (now wiki) answer. (I wanted it noted here to help keep things straight).

Comment: @Someone_Evil Anything that will help will help.  Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth we have other questions specific details of  PHB+1: [Do the AL PHB+1 restrictions work on the character's archetype?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116152/52137), [During Adventurers League character creation, are the listed variant options always available even if the associated book is not chosen as my PHB+1?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157450/52137)

Comment: @Someone_Evil so maybe not a dupe?  You may have an answer there ...

Comment: ALthough for those specific questions, there is a specific question. This one is just a general question asking what +1 really means, no?

Comment: @NautArch I have to step away from it, maybe I misunderstand what the questioner wants.

Comment: @NautArch And now that the original wiki's q&a has been updated, perhaps it returns to being a dupe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## They're different, but perhaps only subtly so

(Full disclosure, I know the answer to the closed question and fully intend to answer it should it get reopened.)

The (current) [target](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110848/52137) is essentially asking: From only knowing the name, what is the "PHB+1" rule. The answer to such a question is expected to be where to find the rule, and *generally* how it works.

The (current) dupe is asking about the nature of a *specific* part of that rule. It already knows where to find it and how the rule generally works. As such it is similar to other questions we have (non-exhaustive list) which are asking about specific problems with the "PHB+1" rule:

- [Do the AL PHB+1 restrictions work on the character's archetype?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116152/52137)
- [During Adventurers League character creation, are the listed variant options always available even if the associated book is not chosen as my PHB+1?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157450/52137)

While the general answer could give a clarification so as to answer the specific problem, that would

1. expand the scope and length of the answer substantially,
2. clutter the answer with detail that isn't of relevance to many other readers,
3. Bury the answer to the specific question in the general one, making it equally hard for someone with the specific problem to find that answer as it is to figure it out themselves.
4. and there is no end to the possible misunderstandings one could have with the rule, multiplying the above rule.

So, keeping it closed as a dupe isn't benefiting either question (or its answers), as such it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: Answer away, you have made a good case

Comment: I like the way you thought through this. Sorry it tool so long to hit 'accept'